# How do I solve this partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

I am trying to solve the following pde:

$$(x+z)u_x + (y+z)u_y + (x+y)u_z = 0$$

My attempt is writing the following characteristic equations

$$\frac{dx}{x+z}= \frac{dy}{y+z} = \frac{dz}{x+y}= \frac{du}{0} $$

and then
$$ \frac{dy -dz}{z-x}= \frac{dz-dx}{y-z}$$

From here I am stuck, I tried using the relationship of the $d$ operator to get
$$ \frac{d(y -z)}{z-x}= \frac{d(z-x)}{y-z}$$
and then integrated the expression above by substituting $y-z$ with $t$ but it feels like its not right. What approach could I use to solve this pde

Comment: You say you are stuck but don't explain where, nor why ' it feels like its not right'. You have $$\frac{d(y-z)}{z-x} = \frac{d(z-x)}{y-z} \implies (y-z)d(y-z) = (z-x)d(z-x) \implies d \left( \frac{(y-z)^{2}}{2} \right) = d \left( \frac{(z-x)^{2}}{2} \right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x+z)u_x + (y+z)u_y + (x+y)u_z = 0$$

You correctly wrote the Charpit-Lagrange ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x+z}= \frac{dy}{y+z} = \frac{dz}{x+y}= \frac{du}{0} $$

Also you correctly found one of the linear combinaison of ODEs :
$\quad \frac{dy -dz}{z-x}= \frac{dz-dx}{y-z}$

A first characteristic equation comes from solving it :

$(y-z)(dy-dz)=(z-x)(dz-dx)\quad\implies\quad (y-z)^2=(z-x)^2+c_1$. After simplification :
$$(y-x)(x+y-2z)=c_1$$

Another linear combination of the three ODEs leads to :
$$\frac{dx}{x+z}= \frac{dy}{y+z} = \frac{dz}{x+y}= \frac{dx+dy-2dz}{(x+z)+(y+z)-2(x+y)} =\frac{dx+dy-2dz}{0}$$
This implies $(dx+dy-2dz)=0$ and a second characteristic equation :
$$x+y-2z=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is :
$$u(x,t,z)=F\big((y-x)(x+y-2z)\:\:,\:\:(x+y-2z) \big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function of two variables.

Comment: I understand your approach clearly, I was thinking also if I write another linear combination as $$\frac{dx}{x+z}= \frac{dy}{y+z} = \frac{dz}{x+y}=\frac{2dz}{2(x+y)}$$ and then  $$\frac{d(x-y)}{x-y}= \frac{d(2z-x-y)}{-(2z-x-y)}$$ which would give another characteristic equation $\frac{x+y+z}{(x-y)^2}$. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096131/solve-this-pde-yzu-xzxu-yxyu-z-0) should help, with $A= \left(\begin{array}{lll} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right).$

Comment: Thanks for the approach of using a system of equations, does this mean with characteristics it cannot be solved explicitly?

Comment: This method gives the characteristics of the PDE. [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Method_of_characteristics#/Linear_and_quasilinear_cases).